# git lfs looses execute flag on hook scripts

Tags: git, githooks, git-lfs

A weird issue where scripts in `.git/hooks` directory (e.g. `post-commit`, `post-merge`, etc) loose their `+x` flag rendering them useless.

Environment is macOS.  Git version is `2.15.1`, git lfs version is `git-lfs/2.3.4 (GitHub; darwin amd64; go 1.9.1)`

Troubleshooting the issue I found that even if I manually run `chmod a+x .git/hooks/*`, verify that `x` is set on all the files, and then perform `git checkout <whatever>`, the `x` is reset and is gone.  It does it no matter if I checkout `master` or some branch.

Additionally, even running `git lfs install` doesn't resolve the issue, and after command runs (standard messages written to console), the command doesn't place `+x` on those files.

What is the way to fix this issue?